# Failing installation while installing php-libgit2 php

Tags: php, git, libgit2

I am trying to install libgit2 and php-git. I've successfully downloaded and built libgit2.However, I face problem when I try to install php-git.

This is how I try to install it :

```
phpize
./configure --enable-git2-debug
make
make install
```

There's no problem with phpize. However, when I use make and make install, following errors are showed:

```
./php_git2.h:180:3: error: unknown type name 'git_smart_subtransport'
                git_smart_subtransport *smart_subtransport;

./helper.h:58:42: error: unknown type name 'git_checkout_opts'; did you mean 'git_checkout_options'?
void php_git2_git_checkout_opts_to_array(git_checkout_opts *opts, zval **out TSRMLS_DC);

/usr/local/include/git2/checkout.h:295:3: note: 'git_checkout_options' declared here
} git_checkout_options;
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

./helper.h:62:41: error: unknown type name 'git_checkout_opts'; did you mean 'git_checkout_options'?
int php_git2_array_to_git_checkout_opts(git_checkout_opts **out, zval *array TSRMLS_DC);
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                        git_checkout_options
```

and there are more errors. Why this happens?

Answer (score 2):

These errors indicate that the header files for libgit2 do not correspond to the version which the PHP bindings expect.

The bindings have their own libgit2 version which they link statically, so it does not need/want to use a system-installed version, but this is where the header files are being read from (as indicated by the paths in the output).

It looks to be a bug in php-git that it reads system header files for libgit2, but that's the root of the issue. The bindings do not want you to install libgit2 on your system. Unless you need a system libgit2 for another purpose, removing it should fix the issue.

You should file a bug with the php-git project as failing to work when a version of libgit2 is installed on the system is a build system bug in its code.

Answer (score 0):

I should have been clearer.  Looks like it's not finding libgit2.